# Unable to overload Python stdout writing correctly (Tee class)

Tags: python

I use since a lot of time an example found on the internet about overloading the write method of sys.stdout by using the following class:

```
class Tee(object):
    """
    Redirect output to each object given as parameter
    """
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def __del__(self):
        for f in self.files:
            f.close()
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)
    def flush(self):
        for file in self.files:
            file.flush()

sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, open(logFile, "w"))
```

This works like a charm, it prints something on the console and in the same time writes to a file.

Recently I wanted to add date and time to each of my outputs to be able to investigate my program more accurately.

So here is what I have changed in the above code :

```
def write(self, obj):
    text = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " - " + obj
    for f in self.files:
        f.write(text)
```

But now I'm getting something weird: the date is added at the beginning of the line I want to output and ALSO to the end...

Searching and trying a bit on my own, I found that each time I use `print("blablabla")` in my code, the line is getting written but also a second empty element (or a new line, I'm not entirely sure), which is why I'm getting the second date at the end of the line.

While I'm writing this, it makes me think that the write method works in 2 steps, one being outputting the "thing", and second outputing the new line character...

It works by creating a new method like below:

```
def myPrint(obj):
    text = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " - " + obj
    print(text)
```

but now I can't use the native `print` method in my code, which is a bit ennoying.

Is there any solution or piece I'm missing to work around this?

Thanks !

EDIT:
This is what I get when I try to add the date with the above code:

```
2022-08-02 09:33:20 - *** output line 12022-08-02 09:33:20 - 
2022-08-02 09:33:20 - output line 22022-08-02 09:33:20 - 
2022-08-02 09:33:20 - output line 32022-08-02 09:33:20 -
```

Which is transformed to the following when I add the "\n" at the end as suggested by @azro:

```
2022-08-02 09:33:20 - *** output line 1
2022-08-02 09:33:20 - 

2022-08-02 09:33:20 - output line 2
2022-08-02 09:33:20 - 

2022-08-02 09:33:20 - output line 3
2022-08-02 09:33:20 -
```

Comment: Hi, I would suggest to invest some time reading about the `logging` module of python. You are reinventing the wheel. Typically you use a logger for this task and add handlers to write into various files (also filtering the log-level and formatting per file etc.).

Comment: Hmmm ! Great thanks ! I will have a deep look at this :)

Comment: Here is a starting point: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Answer (score 0):

The `print` method has `\n` as default end, `write` has not, so add one

```
def write(self, obj):
    text = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " - " + obj + "\n"
    for f in self.files:
        f.write(text)
```

But that issue shouldn't appear with that date update, you sould had it before too, if you don't pass a string that ends with a newline what, then it's write on same line in the file

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried this, but I just end up with new lines and empty lines. It just push the ending date to a new line.

Comment: I have edited my initial post with samples of what I get in both codes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, I would suggest to use the `logging` module instead of monkey patching `sys.stdout`. This said, the problem in your code is to determine when to put the timestamp. This is not a trivial question, because you could have multi line messages but maybe you do not want a timestamp in front of each. But sometimes you also call the write method of stream with only a part of the line and add more later on. This is what happens when using `print`. It writes the provided content and calls again with the line separator (see `end` arguments of the print function).

So here is a possible way to solve the problem:

```py
import sys
import os
import datetime

class Tee(object):
    """
    Redirect output to each object given as parameter
    """
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
        self.addtimestamp = True
    def __del__(self):
        for f in self.files:
            f.close()
    def write(self, text):
        if self.addtimestamp:
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            text = f"{timestamp} - {text}"
            self.addtimestamp = False
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(text)
        if text.endswith(os.linesep):
            self.addtimestamp = True
    def flush(self):
        for file in self.files:
            file.flush()
```

The idea is to check if the text has ended with a line separator to decide if the next call should again prepend the timestamp.

Comment: Wow I didn't receive a notification for this one! Seems awesome! I will give it a try for sure at some point, it makes a lot of sense to me now that it is said ;) Thanks a lot!